# About compatibility between specific printer and Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: printing, compatibility

Is an HP photosmart P1000, model c6723a compatible with Ubuntu 12.04 OS?  I can't find this out from HP or anywhere I have researched.  Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu support variety of printers:

Here are supported  printers https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Printers and also you can take a look https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrinters

For your case  `HP photosmart P1000, model c6723a`  , according to https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrintersHp it has no support yet.

But you still can use a generic driver for your printer.
Please take a look  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HPPrinterInstallation

and if you like there is nice tutorial about printing in linux  can be found http://linuxibos.blogspot.com/2012/05/seprinters-linux.html